# Can i start my AWS RDS instance in bootstrap action of EMR creation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, rds

I am using a RDS instance as an external hive metastore, can i start my AWS RDS instance in bootstrap action of EMR creation?

Comment: What do you mean by start RDS Instance ? spin up a new RDS Instance  ?

Comment: RDS is designed to be a 24x7 service. You can shutdown RDS for up to one week, but it will automatically restart.

Comment: @jc i just want to start the instance from stopped state in bootstrap action.is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can. All EMR's EC2 instances will assume instance profile role -  **EMR_EC2_DefaultRole** by default. Which means if you have proper permissions on that EC2 instance profile role that you use for EMR, you can run AWS CLI commands on your Bootstrap Action script to start RDS Instance. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-iam-roles.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/start-db-instance.html